# Tutorial to install hadoop To Analyse => millions of data

Tags: hadoop, installation, mapreduce, mapr

I need to install hadoop to analyse data, show statistics, and develop an application  from it. 
And I need to know if I need a windows/linux machine? How many datanodes/namenodes will I need? Is there any tutorial for this?

**More precision:**
I have to analyse data that contains Calls infos (millions or more of data), and show the statistics in an interface (application) using hadoop . so to begin i must install hadoop , but i need to know what do i need ,how many machines etc.

Comment: http://www.highlyscalablesystems.com/3597/hadoop-installation-tutorial-hadoop-2-x/. Its impossible for others to answer without knowing the exact needs. Narrow down your question.

Comment: I'm going to second the broad question issue brought up by Ramanan R. You've more or less just asked "How does one Hadoop?" That's more than we can answer here. For hadoop you'll  want to start by [reading the docs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/index.htm). And for Stack Overflow, you'll want to start, well, [reading the docs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: What Doomy said - you need to read up a lot more on architecture, distributions, etc.  For instance - only Hortonworks allows a Windows based install; they and all the others use Linux.

Comment: I installed hadoop on ubuntu server , works fine , my question is , i need to explore data and make statistics of it , i know i may use R studio , but i need to develop my own interface that shows those statistics .